# SAP B1 HANA Query - Where Condition not working

Tags: hana, sapb1

I have the following query, which seems to be working, except for the last where conditions:

```sql
WHERE 
    ( ( T2."WhsCode" = ( '03' ) OR T2."WhsCode" = ( '33' ) ) 

    AND 

    ( ( T1."WhsCode" <> ( '03' ) OR T1."WhsCode" <> ( '33' ) ) 

    OR 

    T0."DocNum" IS NULL ) )
```

It doesn't seem to take into account the second part (after the AND). Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

The full code bellow:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT T0."DocNum" AS "QUOT DocNum", T0."CANCELED"  AS "QUOT Canc", T3."DocNum" AS "OC DocNum",  T3."CANCELED" AS "OC Canc", T5."DocNum" AS "RECP DocNum", T5."CANCELED" AS "RECP Canc", T0."DocDate" AS "Env Date", T0."ReqDate" AS "Lev Date", T3."DocDate" AS "OC Date", T5."DocDate" AS "Recp Date", T1."LineNum", CONCAT(REPLACE(T1."ItemCode",'.','_'),'_') AS SKU, T1."ItemCode", T1."WhsCode", T2."LineNum", CONCAT(REPLACE(T2."ItemCode",'.','_'),'_') AS SKU, T2."ItemCode", T2."WhsCode", T1."PQTReqQty" AS "Qtt_Pedida", T1."Quantity" AS "Qtt_Env", T2."Quantity" AS "Qtt_OC", T4."Quantity" AS "Qtt_Rec", CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((WEEKDAY(ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2))=5) OR (WEEKDAY(ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2))=6)) THEN ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",4) ELSE ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2) END)>=CURRENT_DATE THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS "Aft_Tdy", CASE WHEN (T0."CANCELED"='N' OR T0."CANCELED" IS NULL) AND (T3."CANCELED"='N' OR T3."CANCELED" IS NULL) AND (T5."CANCELED" IS NULL OR T5."CANCELED"='N') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS "Consid"

FROM OPQT T0 LEFT JOIN PQT1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" LEFT JOIN POR1 T2 ON T1."TrgetEntry"= T2."DocEntry" AND T1."LineNum"=T2."BaseLine" LEFT JOIN OPOR T3 ON T2."DocEntry" = T3."DocEntry" LEFT JOIN PDN1 T4 ON  T2."LineNum"=T4."BaseLine" AND T2."DocEntry"=T4."BaseEntry" LEFT JOIN OPDN T5 ON T4."DocEntry" = T5."DocEntry" WHERE (T1."WhsCode"='03' OR T1."WhsCode"='33')

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT T0."DocNum" AS "QUOT DocNum", T0."CANCELED"  AS "QUOT Canc", T3."DocNum" AS "OC DocNum",  T3."CANCELED" AS "OC Canc", T5."DocNum" AS "RECP DocNum", T5."CANCELED" AS "RECP Canc", T0."DocDate" AS "Env Date", T0."ReqDate" AS "Lev Date", T3."DocDate" AS "OC Date", T5."DocDate" AS "Recp Date", T1."LineNum", CONCAT(REPLACE(T1."ItemCode",'.','_'),'_') AS SKU, T1."ItemCode", T1."WhsCode", T2."LineNum", CONCAT(REPLACE(T2."ItemCode",'.','_'),'_') AS SKU, T2."ItemCode", T2."WhsCode", T1."PQTReqQty" AS "Qtt_Pedida", T1."Quantity" AS "Qtt_Env", T2."Quantity" AS "Qtt_OC", T4."Quantity" AS "Qtt_Rec", CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN ((WEEKDAY(ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2))=5) OR (WEEKDAY(ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2))=6)) THEN ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",4) ELSE ADD_DAYS(T0."ReqDate",2) END)>=CURRENT_DATE THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS "Aft_Tdy", CASE WHEN (T0."CANCELED"='N' OR T0."CANCELED" IS NULL) AND (T3."CANCELED"='N' OR T3."CANCELED" IS NULL) AND (T5."CANCELED" IS NULL OR T5."CANCELED"='N') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS "Consid"

FROM OPOR T3 LEFT JOIN POR1 T2 ON T2."DocEntry" = T3."DocEntry" LEFT JOIN PQT1 T1 ON T1."TrgetEntry"= T2."DocEntry" AND T1."LineNum"=T2."BaseLine" LEFT JOIN OPQT T0 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" LEFT JOIN PDN1 T4 ON  T2."LineNum"=T4."BaseLine" AND T2."DocEntry"=T4."BaseEntry" LEFT JOIN OPDN T5 ON T4."DocEntry" = T5."DocEntry" WHERE ( ( T2."WhsCode" = ( '03' ) OR T2."WhsCode" = ( '33' ) ) AND ( ( T1."WhsCode" <> ( '03' ) OR T1."WhsCode" <> ( '33' ) ) OR T0."DocNum" IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: You know in SAP tables we don't have NULL as native HANA database tables. Did you try to check with empty string instead of NULL like DocNum = '' or DocNum = '          '  , etc?

Comment: Hi @Eralper, no I did not know that (I haven't had any training in using SAP so I'm learning as I go along). I'm going to reformulate my query and post the results. Thanks

Comment: Actually just had some time to try it out, I get exactly the same result. I'm starting to wonder about the integrity of the hole query

Comment: Hi @BrunoR, actually this OR clause is always true: T1."WhsCode" <> ( '03' ) OR T1."WhsCode" <> ( '33' )    So the other OR part where you are working on does not change anything. As a result for the second SELECT statement the active or effecting criteria is : T2."WhsCode" = ( '03' ) OR T2."WhsCode" = ( '33' )

Comment: @Eralper, you nailed it. Hadn't considered that the logic might have been wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Eralper: NULL and empty string are different in HANA like in other databases. And NULL is no table!

Comment: @Christian4143, hi. I know difference between NULL and empty string. What I actually want to take attention is in SAP tables we have initial values for alpha-numeric fields which are stored as empty strings in HANA tables. In other applications, generally these fields are kept as NULL values.